# How to set angular sidebar mode to side "mat-sidenav"

Tags: angular

I am new in angular
I am using angular 8
I am using angular material in my project
I used mat-sidenav and I just want to set its mode to "side" to appear side-by-side with the main content, But it does not work . It is always "over" or "push"
This is my html code

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav" fixedInViewport="true" [attr.role]="'navigation'" mode="'side'" opened="false">
    <mat-toolbar>
      <a class="home-button" routerLink="/">
        <img class="app-logo" src="assets/home-logo.png" />
      </a>


    </mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list class="navigation-list">
      <a class="navigation-item" mat-list-item routerLink="/route1" routerLinkActive="active">
        <mat-icon class="material-icons">create</mat-icon>

      </a>
      <mat-divider class="navigation-divider"></mat-divider>
      <a class="navigation-item" mat-list-item routerLink="/route2" routerLinkActive="active">
        <mat-icon class="material-icons">how_to_reg</mat-icon><span class="navigation-item-label">My second link</span>
      </a>
      <a class="navigation-item" mat-list-item routerLink="/route3" routerLinkActive="active">
        <mat-icon class="material-icons">add_comment</mat-icon><span class="navigation-item-label">My third link</span>
      </a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content class="sidenav-content">

    <mat-toolbar class="sidenav-content-toolbar" color="primary">
      <div class="container">
      <div class="row align-items-start">
        <div class="col-1 d-flex justify-content-start">
          <button mat-icon-button class="menu-button" type="button" aria-label="Toggle sidenav" (tap)="drawer.toggle()">
            <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col">Welcome</div>
        <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-end">
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Logout</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>

    </mat-toolbar>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-login></app-login>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: You don't need quotes here: `mode="'side'"`. `mode="side"` or `[mode]="'side'"`. When you use data binding ([input]="") it expect a property. When you don't use it (input="") it expect string

Comment: @Angular WOW is is fixed   Thank you soooo much